# In JavaScript why Number() function does not work here and gives back a string?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have this simple example and can not figure out the solution. Can somebody please tell me why n is still a string after used the Number() function? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Still a string</title>
<style>
  input {
    width: 30px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
    n = <input type="number" id="n"><br/>

    <button id="but" onclick="gen()">Push me!</button>

    <script>
        var n;
        function gen() {
        n = document.getElementById("n").value;
        Number(n);
        alert(typeof n);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You... haven't done anything with the return value. `n = Number(n)` might do what you want?

Comment: Number is not a mutator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primitive data types (Strings, numbers, boolean etc.) in javascript are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

So, whenever you change String "n" to number, a number is stored on memory but "n" is still referring to the same String.

Instead you should type your code as:

```
var n;
function gen() {
    n = document.getElementById("n").value;
    n = Number(n);
    alert(typeof n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Shame on me... what a mistake!

Comment: Hey @Lumpy79, I know that feeling and believe me that happens when you start learning it first.

Answer (score 2):

`Number` does not convert parameter to number but returns number, try this:

```
function gen() {
    var n = document.getElementById('n').value;
    var num = Number(n);
    alert(typeof num);
}
```